# Query live data from large MongoDB collection - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, large-data

I want to get last 10 records and newest record which just added. 
I tried to use tailable cursor but it took me too much time because it have to scan entire collection before reach the end of collection to wait data.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe349d0ef0edb520f0ca29"),
    "topic" : "IoTeam/messages/",
    "payload" : "20:15:04:01:12:75,-127.00,679",
    "qos" : 0,
    "retain" : false,
    "_msgid" : "45975d0d.ba68a4",
    "mac" : "20:15:04:01:12:75",
    "temp" : "-127.00",
    "hum" : "679",
    "time" : "01/04/2016 15:43:09"
}
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: There are many things you can do to help increase mongodb performance, but without more information we can't help.  Post your schema design, and what exactly you're trying to do and then it will be easier to provide recommendations.

Comment: hi. thank for your answer.

Comment: i want to query 10 last records and live data records. With small collection its fine when using tailable cursor, but with large collection (about 20000 records) tailable cursor takes too much time to scan from the first record to the last record.      {
 "_id" : ObjectId("56fe349d0ef0edb520f0ca29"),
 "topic" : "IoTeam/messages/",
 "payload" : "20:15:04:01:12:75,-127.00,679",
 "qos" : 0,
 "retain" : false,
 "_msgid" : "45975d0d.ba68a4",
 "mac" : "20:15:04:01:12:75",
 "temp" : "-127.00",
 "hum" : "679",
 "time" : "01/04/2016 15:43:09"
}

Comment: Which field are you querying against?

Comment: @Ajmera: i want to query field _id

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Is the `time` field for the time when a particular record gets inserted?

Comment: The time filed is created by me because i dont want to convert _id to time.

Comment: Yeah, but is it the time at which the record is inserted in the collection?

Comment: Yes, its the time that the record inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Still difficult to say the best solution without knowing more information.  But here is one suggestion that you could try (all using the mongo shell)

Create an index on the time key.

```
db.your_collection_name.createIndex({time:-1})
```

After you have created the index, type the following to ensure it was done correctly.

```
db.your_collection_name.getIndexes()
```

This will list your indexes, and you should see that a new one was added for the time key.

**Caution:** Although this will reduce the amount of time it takes to query on the time key, it will increase the amount of time it takes to insert new records into your database.  This is due to the fact that new inserts will need to be indexed.  So take that into consideration when scaling your app, and it may mean down the road you will want to handle this in a different way.

Comment: sorry for my bad english. My problem is just the as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592542/how-do-i-move-a-tailable-cursor-with-awaitdata-to-the-end-so-i-just-get-new-upda

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create an index on the field `time`.

```
db.collection('nameOfYourCollection')
  .createIndex(
      { "time": -1 },
      null,
      function(err, results){
          console.log(results);
      });
```

This will create an index on the `time` field of your collection. This might take some time. But once the index is created, the queries will be much faster.

After this in your query just do this :

```
var cursor = db.collection('nameOfYourCollection').find().sort([ ["time", -1] ]).limit(10);
cursor.forEach(function(doc){
    if(doc) console.log("Got the document as : " + JSON.stringify(doc));
}, function(err){
    if(err) console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

This will give you the last 10 records that were inserted in the collection.

You can also call `toArray` instead of `forEach` in the `cursor`. Something like this :

```
var cursor = db.collection('nameOfYourCollection').find().sort([ ["time", -1] ]).limit(10);
cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){
    if(err) console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    if(docs){
        console.log("Got the document as : " + JSON.stringify(docs));
        console.log("This is the latest record that was inserted : " + JSON.stringify(docs[0]));
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i also need to track new record inserted in real-time